# How do I keep from changing all the id's using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="date_container" id="date_container_0" >
                <div class="day">
            <div class="date">

            </div><!--end date--> 
        </div><!--end day--> 
                <div class="day">
            <div class="date">

            </div><!--end date--> 
        </div><!--end day--> 
                <div class="day">
            <div class="date">

            </div><!--end date--> 
        </div><!--end day--> 
                <div class="day">
            <div class="date">

            </div><!--end date--> 
        </div><!--end day--> 
                <div class="day">
            <div class="date">

            </div><!--end date--> 
        </div><!--end day--> 
                <div class="day">
            <div class="date">

            </div><!--end date--> 
        </div><!--end day--> 
                <div class="day">
            <div class="date">

            </div><!--end date--> 
        </div><!--end day--> 
            <div class="nav_buttons">
        <button class="previous">Previous</button>
        <button class="next">Next</button>
    </div><!--end nav_buttons--> 
</div><!--end date_container-->
```

I want to dynamically add id's to each of the `day` classes. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    $(".date").each(function(i){

    var weekday=new Array(7);
    weekday[0]="Sunday";
    weekday[1]="Monday";
    weekday[2]="Tuesday";
    weekday[3]="Wednesday";
    weekday[4]="Thursday";
    weekday[5]="Friday";
    weekday[6]="Saturday";



    var nDate = new Date(); 
    var mDate = new Date(nDate).setDate(nDate.getDate()+i); 
    var d = new Date(mDate);
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
    var day = d.getDate();
    var wDay = weekday[d.getDay()]; 
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    if(day <= 9){
        day = "0" + day; 
    }

    $(this).append('<h4>'+month+'/'+day+'/'+year+'</h4>');
    $(this).append('<h6>'+wDay+'</h6>');
    console.log("Month: "+month);
    console.log("day: "+day);
    console.log("Year: "+year);

    $(this).parent().parent().find(".day").attr("id", "_"+month+"-"+day+"-"+year); 
});
```

The above code is also adding the date to the date element.

The problem is that when the ID's are added, they are all the same. More specifically, they are the same as the last `day` class. It seems like the code I'm using is updating all the id's, rather than just the element I'm on.

Here is what it looks like after the Javascript is run:

[image]

How do I get each class to have it's own unique id?

Comment: Should your question be "how to I stop this from updating all the id's?"

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().attr("id", "_"+month+"-"+day+"-"+year);
```

instead of

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".day").attr("id", "_"+month+"-"+day+"-"+year);
```

By using `$(this).parent().parent().find(".day")` you find **all** `.day` elements within date_container

Comment: There we go! That was it! Thank you!

Comment: It's working man. Either you changed the code, or I miss read it, but your last edit got it working perfectly.